# Smalltalk equivalent to Common Lisp's #| ... |# comments?

Tags: common-lisp, smalltalk

Common Lisp's multiline comments make it easier to include multiline shebangs:

```
#!/bin/bash
#|
exec clisp -q -q $0 $0 ${1+"$@"}
exit
|#

;;; Usage: ./scriptname.lisp

(defun main (args)
 (let ((program (car args)))
  (format t "Program: ~a~%" program)
  (quit)))
```

Without this syntax, only very simple shebangs can be used. Is there a pound-based multiline comment for Smalltalk that would facilitate multiline shebangs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't NEED to be multi-line; as long as bash can see "into" the Smalltalk comment, you should be okay.  I'd be more worried about Smalltalk seeing past the #!

How about something based on:

`"exec" "/usr/bin/gst" "--foo" "$0" "--bar" "$@"`

There's no need for `exit` unless you expect the `exec` ever to fail.  Make sure your Smalltalk is where you expect it to be!  If you do want the safety valve:

```
"exec" ...
"exit"
```

Having to double-quote arguments can get in the way, of course.  Double-quoting shell operators breaks their specialness, for example.

```
"echo" "hello" ">" "/dev/null"
```

just prints "hello > /dev/null"

Comment: I thought of it just after you did! :) There's one minor problem: the quotes join all the arguments after the script name as one. But that's easy to handle. I don't suppose there's a getopt library for Smalltalk?

Comment: Bernd, do you know of Smalltalk syntax that emulates Python's `if __name__=="__main__": main()`?

Comment: "$@" expands to all the shell args, each as a separate word.  This is different to "$*".  I may have missed your point.  And no, can't help with __name__ == "__main__" trick.